# gem 'protector' controlling actions in rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, protector

Protector is about controlling models.

How can I deal with controllers `#new` & `#edit` actions?

They do not interact with database, but render views that shouldn't be rendered. I should get an error this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Protector does not work on controller level. However you can use meta methods like `can?` to evaluate your permission block and get the result even if you don't use models directly.

Comment: Do I need to create a custom `before_filter` in ApplicationController or is there any way to process this logic?

Comment: Any standard way will work. Either use filter or inject it straight to controller action.

Comment: This seems little ugly ;)